Low fees transactions
I m a new here and looking for help, altought I''m not a developer or IT oriented person. I will start from the fact, that I own some worthless Solana Tokens, and I'd like to retrevie some money from it. I found a way to do it by burning it, bit by bit, and recovering 0,002 Sol from incineration sites. The problems is, that I'll have to store the whole bunch of this tokens in one place ( kind of safe) and then, send it bit by bit to wallet, where I can burn it, but sending fee is about 0,002 Sol or more, which make te whole idea no sense. However, I noticed some sites ( especially games based on Solana chain) where you can deposit and withdraw their tokens for less than 0.00005-8 Sol (5,000 lamports per signature ). Anyone knows, which tool, or protocol they use?
